# I need to calculate the time between dates in different lines. (PLSQL)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table where I store all status changes and the time that it has been made. So, when I search the order number on the table of times I get all the dates of my changes, but what I realy want is the time (hours/minutes) that the order was in each status.

The table of time seems like this

```
ID_ORDER |  Status   | Date
1         Waiting     27/09/2017 12:00:00
1         Late        27/09/2017 14:00:00
1         In progress 28/09/2017 08:00:00
1         Validating  30/09/2017 14:00:00
1         Completed   30/09/2017 14:00:00
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*, 
       (lead(date) over (partition by id_order order by date) - date) as time_in_order
from t;
```

Comment: thanks, I think it has work exactly how I need, but the return field is a little confusing for me. Can you especify the return? Thanks a lot!!!